# How can I insert data into a temporary table

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression, temp-tables

Is there a way to insert the results of this query into a temporary table in SSMS? I have tried a number of ways but failed thus far.

Or is there another way, all I al looking for it to query the results of this and join another table which I can't seem to do in the query itself.

```
USE CommDB

;With CTE AS (SELECT s.attendanceNumber, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 1 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 2 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 3 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 4 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 5 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode5,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 6 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode6,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 7 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode7,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 8 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode8,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 9 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode9,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 10 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode10,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 11 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode11,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 12 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode12,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 13 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode13,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 14 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode14
FROM (
    SELECT  [AttendanceNumber]
           ,[ExaminationDate]
           ,RadiologyID
           ,[ExamExaminationCode]
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [AttendanceNumber]
            ORDER BY [ExamExaminationCode]) as rnk --Ordered ASC so examcodes dont move 

      FROM [CommDB].[dbo].[tblRadiologyData] rd 
      where rd.ExaminationDate >= '01 october 2015'
      and   rd.AttendanceSiteCode IN('CNM','RNM') ) s
GROUP BY s.attendanceNumber)

Select c.examCode1,
         c.examCode2,
         c.examCode3,
         c.examCode4,
         c.examCode5,
         c.examCode6,
         c.examCode7,
         c.examCode8,
         c.examCode9,
         c.examCode10,
         c.examCode11,
         c.examCode12,
         c.examCode13,
         c.examCode14,
         c.AttendanceNumber,
         COUNT(c.AttendanceNumber) as [No of occurances]
--       (Select lu.HRGCode from CommDB.dbo.tblRadiologyNucMedLookup lu
--        Where ISNULL(c.examCode1,'') = ISNULL(lu.Exam01,'') 
--        )
from CTE c




GROUP by c.examCode1,
         c.examCode2,
         C.examCode3,
         C.examCode4,
         C.examCode5,
         C.examCode6,
         C.examCode7,
         C.examCode8,
         C.examCode9,
         C.examCode10,
         C.examCode11,
         C.examCode12,
         C.examCode13,
         C.examCode14,
         C.AttendanceNumber


ORDER BY C.examCode1
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? In addition, you mention that you are trying to join to another table, but the script you posted doesn't have any joins.

Comment: `select .... into #someTemp from CTE group by....`

Answer (score 0):

With pivot statement your live will be much easier - you don't need cte.

And your question - there are several types of temporary tables:

1. global temporary table - prefixed with ## (you can access this table from other sessions)
2. session temporary table - prefixed with # (you can access this table only from session)
3. variable temporary - must be declared and prefixed with @ (you can access this table only in one batch)
4. table on tempdb - common table, but after administration tasks (restart service) will be deleted

other:

5. you can use view or TVF instead of temporary tables (it is another way)
6. you can utilize potencial of CTE (most people use it only as view)

Type 1,2,4 you can create as standard table (with create statement or script select into).
Type 3 you have to declare as variable.

Example of session temporary table:

```
    create table #TmpTable (id int, col1 varchar(5), col2 varchar(5))

    insert into #TmpTable (id, col1, col2) select 1, 'KSDFA', 'ASDAS' -- from tbl
```